# How to calculate of SUM of values?

Tags: php

i am new in PHP. I am trying to SUM of values which i am fetching from database. Would you tell me how to calculate of fetch data from database. Below i am showing you the output and code of PHP. I want total of Amount values

[This is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwEWF.jpg)

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried to get this solved already?

Comment: `SUM()` function. Go forth and have fun.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sum of amount then go with this

Example SQL query:

```
select sum(column_name) as total from your table_name
```

Then fetch the result in PHP

```
echo $fetched_data['total'];
```